# how greater than/less than works internally

Tags: java, comparison, integer

how greater than/less than works internally

how much performance hit will be there if i compare 5 with 100 vs 5 with 2,147,483,647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)

```
5 < 100 and 5 < Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

I am asking this question because in some code rank= Integer.MAX_VALUE is returned when data is not present and we will discard data even if rank is greater than 100, so will there be some considerably improvement if i return 101 instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE. I am getting file of millions of records and i have to do this comparison for every record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how much performance hit will be there if i compare 5 with 100 vs 5 with 2,147,483,647

On all 32- and 64-bit hardware architectures that I am familiar with the two comparisons would take exactly the same amount of time.

The way to improve performance is by focusing on the *number of comparisons* that you make (and, more generally, the amount of work your algorithm has to carry out).

Comment: +1 Note: if the `5` is a short or byte, the code could be optimised away by the JIT. In that case, size would matter.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any difference, so long as the number is small (IE, not 64 bit). And the 64 bit would only make a difference if you were comparing 64 bit numbers. This is typically a single cycle (Or fixed number of small cycles) request in any CPU I am familiar with. However, it might be a good idea to throw an exception, or something like that, instead of setting the number to a pre-defined range.